# Trouble implementing login to Keycloak with AppAuth

Tags: android, appauth

I am trying to use the AppAuth example app to implement a login on my OAuth2 server (Keycloak).
I am not sure on what to write in the .json file, specifically, in "authorization_endpoint_uri","token_endpoint_uri" and "registration_endpoint_uri".
Could somebody explain to me which would be those URL?

This is my config file so far. When I try to log in, it appears my administrator login page.

```
{
  "client_id": "PowerApp",
  "redirect_uri": "https://appauth.demo-app.io/oauth2redirect",
  "authorization_scope": "openid email profile",
  "discovery_uri": "",
  "authorization_endpoint_uri": "http://192.168.1.108:8080/auth",
  "token_endpoint_uri": "http://192.168.1.108:8080/auth",
  "registration_endpoint_uri": "http://192.168.1.108:8080/auth",
  "https_required": false
}
```

Thank you very much!!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the details of the endpoints which keycloak provides from your keycloak server itself.

If your keycloak server is running on `192.168.1.108:8080`, then the following URL should return a JSON response with the details which you are looking for in addition to other details.
`http://192.168.1.108:8080/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Note: If you are authenticating within a realm which is different than `master` replace that in the URL.

Comment: @Raquel Júdez Bello/@Shailesh:   Can you please share keycloak integrated sample app code  with us.

Comment: any sample app? @ShirishBathe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664553/an-error-occurred-while-executing-doinbackground-for-keyclock-authservice-perf